# WPF Splash Screen w/Dynamic Elements. How?

Tags: c#, wpf, splash-screen

I'm new to WPF, and I need some help.
I have a slow-loading WPF app, so I am displaying a splash screen as a stopgap solution. However, I'd like to be able to have the screen change on each run, and display a different quote in a text area (it's a productivity app, so I'll be using non-sappy yet motivating quotes).

I wouldn't post this question if it didn't have broader applicability, of course. Many others need to display version numbers, license info, or loading progress in WPF apps.

Bottom line: Is it possible to create a fast-loading native code splash screen with dynamic text elements, and display it for a WPF app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stefan Olson has implemented a native code splash screen for WPF. You can read about it on his blog  [here](http://www.olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/A-better-WPF-splash-screen.aspx). Maybe this will be of some help to you?

**Update**

Link no longer active. [Wayback Machine to the rescue! Read the archived page here](http://web.archive.org/web/20090125015102/http://olsonsoft.com/blogs/stefanolson/post/A-better-WPF-splash-screen.aspx)

Comment: Link is no longer valid.

Comment: @kwesoly New link to the archived page. Hope this helps :-)