# WPF Window Cold Start - showing black screen

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a WPF Application using MVVM pattern. Startup window consist of 3 controls `Menu`,`TitleBar` and a `DataGrid`. Currently it takes around 5 seconds to complete all the operations( fetching data from service, dynamically generate `DataGrid` and its rendering) and after that it displays all of a sudden to UI. Problem is, the end user has to wait for 5 seconds to see the window after starting the program. Most of the operations is related to `DataGrid`. So I moved the `DataGrid` related code to `Window Loaded` Event and now the window open suddenly but showing a black screen and after some time it shows the DataGrid with data.

So my aim is to show the window with `Menu` and `TitleBar` and after completing the initial load, do the task to load the `DataGrid` in a background thread so that I can show a loading panel in the view. How can I call that particular method that related to `DataGrid` after completing the initial load?

Also, I can't use Splash screen(it's in the requirement).

Please suggest?

Comment: Use ContentRendered instead of Loaded

Comment: Using MVVM move your data access operations into a background worker and provide some type of loading image gif or label to tell your end user work is being done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should perform any long running process in a background `Thread`... this will free up your UI. If you are not familiar with multi-threaded applications, take a look at the [BackgroundWorker Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) page at MSDN, as it features code examples.

Another thing to note it that you should add `IsAsync="True"` property to your `Binding` declaration on the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` to let it know that it must wait for data. In this way, your `DataGrid` will be displayed empty and then when the data is ready, it will populate.

Comment: In addition to this, a splash screen may be a good choice so a user doesn't stare at empty UI controls until the data loads in. Theres plenty of articles on SO, [here's one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219273/wpf-splash-screen-w-dynamic-elements-how)

Comment: No, it just tells the `Binding` object that it should get and set values asynchronously. See the [Binding.IsAsync Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.isasync.aspx) page at MSDN for more information.